# Как загрузить большой html файл в IE?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Добрый день. Следующая задача - нужно создать большой html файл (около 50000 строк обычного текста), который бы загружался в любом браузере за 5-10 секунд. Сейчас у меня очень простой вариант: `<html><body>текст</body></html>`, и данный файл легко загружается в любом браузере кроме IE за нужное время. В IE же он грузится за время около 30 секунд. Можно ли как то оптимизировать загрузку? Может быть добавить какие-то заголовки, чтобы IE быстрее распознавал, или еще что-то? Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Вы бы указали версию IE.

Comment: разбейте информацию на страницы!

Comment: Версия IE - 8. Насчет разбития на страницы - этого делать нельзя :)

Comment: Если я буду смотреть через мобильный интернет, он все равно будет грузиться долго. Так что разбей на страницы не ленись. Большие тексты на странице многие не любят, такой тон подразумевает что много "воды" в тексте, лучше кусочками читать, на то книги и разбиты страницами, а не как туалетная бумага одним куском на 54 метра.

Comment: Тут дело не в том, что я ленюсь, этого просто по заданию делать нельзя). Эта страница не будет отдаваться сервером, это просто одно из тестовых заданий для одной организации. Поэтому мне нужно именно решение вот этой моей задачи.

Answer (score 1):

советую не грузить такие огромные тексты, желательно разделять их на страницы, а в конце текста делать ссылки на следующею страницу,как продолжение или предыдущую страницу, за одно IE обрабатывать будет быстрее